# ScriptBrowser for Powershell won't run

Tags: script, powershell

I'm trying to run ScriptBrowser for Powershell, but it won't run for me when I click on the shortcut (nothing happens). I tried right clicking on the shortcut to see what it is running, but instead of being a link to an exe file, the target field just says "Microsoft Script Browser".

1. What does it mean when the target field is like that?
2. Anyone know why it might not be running? Or what process I should look for in Task Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have in the shortcut to ScriptBrowser exactly the same target field as you do,
and the "Start in" field contains
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Corporation\Microsoft Script Browser\`.

When I launch it, the process name is :
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Corporation\Microsoft Script Browser\ScriptBrowserDesktop.exe`.

I suggest to verify first that the installation folder exists.
On my computer it contains 60 files in 23 folders taking up 1.48 MB.

If that's also your case, I suggest that you reinstall/repair ScriptBrowser using
"Run as Administrator". If it still won't work, uninstall it, reboot, then reinstall again.
If it still won't start, disable your antivirus or security suite and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the folder and the .exe was missing. I actually resolved the problem though by finding version 1.2 (instead of 1.1) and installing that instead

Comment: A missing .exe is normally caused by an over-active antivirus.